# Shared prefences inside interface

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, retrofit2

I'm using retrofit to get and post some data from the server.
I need the URL from the user, so I saved them in shared preferences, I'm able to read the baseurl in the service file from shared preferences, but I can read them in interface 'JsonPlaceHolderApi' as it needs context and another error is of an attribute value must be constant.

[image]

Comment: post code rather then posting it as image.

Comment: public interface JsonPlaceHolderApi {

    final SharedPreferences mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(JsonPlaceHolderApi.this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit();

   String get= mPreferences.getString("get_url","");
   String post= mPreferences.getString("post_url","");

    @GET(get)
    Call<List<Messages>> getPosts();

    // @Headers({"Content-type : application/json", "charset : UTF-8"})
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST(post)
    Call<MessageStatus> PostStatus(@Field("status") int status, @Field("id") int id);
}

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit could you please suggest something, I'm stuck?

Comment: You can't pass variables into annotation parameters, it must be final. In you case, try making **String get** variable final.

Comment: @JeelVankhede but how can extract value from sharedprefrence inside iterface?

Comment: @TarandeepSingh : I think you can't do this, because every variable in an interface is marked static final by default , so they must be initialized inline, and if you want to use sharedPrefs you must have an instance of context, and you can not pass variables like this to interface. But maybe if you have a helper class you will succeed. i will post answer if find anything

Comment: Don't post code in comments. Use the edit link in the question.

Answer (score 3):

First solution is to use url parameters like this:

```
public interface JsonPlaceholderApi{

    @GET("{get_url}")
    Call<List<Messages>> getPosts(@Path("get_url") String getUrl);

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("{post_url}")
    Call<List<MessageStatus>> PostStatus(@Path("post_url") String postUrl, ....);
}
```

and when you want to call your api pass that url like below:

```
api.getPosts(mPreferences.getString("get_url" , ""))
api.PostStatus(mPreferences.getString("post_url" , ""), ...)
```

---

There is also a tricky solution (which I personally hate it) but you can set urls to some constants and manipulate them in your Interceptor (e.g. replacing them) by reading them from shared preferences.

For example:

```
public interface JsonPlaceholderApi{

    public static final String GET_POSTS_DUMMY_URL = "GET_POSTS_DUMMY_URL";
    public static final String POST_STATUS_DUMMY_URL = "POST_STATUS_DUMMY_URL";

    @GET(GET_POSTS_DUMMY_URL)
    Call<List<Messages>> getPosts();

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST(POST_STATUS_URL)
    Call<List<MessageStatus>> PostStatus(....);
}
```

And then in your retrofit Interceptor's intercept function do something like this:

```
public class RetrofitInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        Request.Builder requestBuilder = request.newBuilder();
        // ...
        requestBuilder.url(request.url().toString()
            .replace(
                JsonPlaceholderApi.GET_POSTS_DUMMY_URL,
                mPreferences.getString("get_url" , "")
            )
            .replace(
                JsonPlaceholderApi.POST_STATUS_DUMMY_URL,
                mPreferences.getString("post_url" , "")
            )
        );
        request = requestBuilder.build();
        // ...
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
}
```

And if you don't know how to add interceptor to retrofit check [this document](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors)

Answer (score 0):

Since the baseUrls are not going to change u can save them statically any where in a separate constants class and get them using the name of the class without using the SharedPreferences

```
class Consts {
    public static final String GET_URL = "put_url_here";
    public static final String POST_URL = "put_url_here";
}
```

then, in the Interface where u need any of them just place:

```
Consts.GET_URL
```

or

```
Consts.POST_URL
```